# CentOS 6 - Order of network interfaces when running "ip address show" command

Tags: linux, centos, networking, ip

I have installed CentOS 6.7 on new HP Gen9 server and decided to rename interfaces using udev so they are in order eth0-7 from left to right when looking at servers back (originally interfaces were in order: eth7, eth6, eth5, eth4, eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3).

Generally udev did the trick but there is one thing that bothers me: when running `ip a` command interfaces are shown in original order that is:

1. lo
2. eth7
3. eth6
4. eth5
5. eth4
6. eth0
7. eth1
8. eth2
9. eth3

When running `netstat -i` or `ifconfig` there is no such problem as interfaces are in alphabetical order, but as `ip a` is the most commonly used, having interfaces mixed is a bit inconvenient. Can anyone give me advice how can I reorder them?